# Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm in registration form(user input)

Tags: django

Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm in admin dashboard.When register user from admin panel everything is ok,but I insert with registration from password is not being hashed.I have only one field for password in registration field.Below is my code

admin.py::

```
    from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
from .models import Employee

class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('email', 'date_of_birth',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'password', 'date_of_birth', 'is_active')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'date_of_birth','created_at','updated_at',)
    list_filter = ()
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('date_of_birth','gender','role',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(Employee, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

models.py::

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password"])
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            name=name,
        )
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



class Employee(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
   ('Male', 'Male'),
   ('Female', 'Female')
    ]
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    role_choice = [
    ('admin', 'admin'),
    ('employee', 'employee') 
    ]
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=role_choice,default="employee")
    is_active = models.BooleanField("IS_ACTIVE",default = True)
    created_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated_at=models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
     return self.email
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
     return self.is_superuser
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
     return True
```

Views.py::

```
from .models import Employee
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .forms import CreateEmployee
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout,  authenticate
from django.contrib import messages

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        takingValue = CreateEmployee(request.POST)
        if takingValue.is_valid():
            takingValue.save()
            user = takingValue.cleaned_data.get('name')
            messages.success(request, 'The account for '  + user + ' created succesfully!')
        return redirect ('login')
    else:
        takingValue = CreateEmployee()
    dis = Employee.objects.all()
    return render (request, 'employee/register.html', {'form':takingValue, 'dis': dis})


def loginPage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password = password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('success')
        else:
            messages.info(request,"Email or Password is incorrect!")

    context={}
    return render(request, 'employee/login.html' , context)


def logoutUser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')




def deleteEmployee(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        deletingValue = Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        deletingValue.delete()
        return redirect('register')

def updateEmployee(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        takingValue =Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        storeValue = CreateEmployee(request.POST, instance=takingValue)
        if takingValue.is_valid():
            takingValue.save()
    else:
        takingValue =Employee.objects.get(pk=id)
        storeValue = CreateEmployee(instance=takingValue)
    return render(request, 'employee/update.html' ,{'form' : storeValue})


def success(request): 
     return render (request, 'employee/success.html')
```

forms.py::

```
    from django import forms
from django.db import models
from .models import Employee
from django.forms.widgets import DateInput
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


UserModel = get_user_model()

GENDER_CHOICES = [
   ('Male', 'Male'),
   ('Female', 'Female')
    ]

role_choice = [
    ('admin', 'admin'),
    ('employee', 'employee') 
    ]

class CreateEmployee(forms.ModelForm):
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    #role = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=role_choice,default="employee")
    # password1 : forms.CharField(label='password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    # password2 : forms.CharField(label='confirm password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['name','email','password','gender','date_of_birth','role']
        widgets = {
            'name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter Your Name', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter Your Email', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password' : forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True,attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter Your Password', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            #'password2' : forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True,attrs={'placeholder' : 'Enter Your Password', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'date_of_birth': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            'role' : forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'btn btn-warning'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved::

In my views.py I changed the code::

From::

```
  if takingValue.is_valid():
        takingValue.save()
```

To::

```
 if takingValue.is_valid():
    upass = takingValue.save(commit=False)
    upass.set_password(takingValue.cleaned_data['password'])
    takingValue.save()
```